# failed to create file: invalid WIN32 path characters

Tags: node-red

I have setup NODE-RED on Windows Server 2016, I have write-file node to write some values in a file.

When I run the flow it gives me the following error:

> Failed to create file: Error  contains invalid WIN32 path characters

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, you should have extracted a [mcve] before even posting here, because without it, your question is considered off-topic. Also, take the time and throw the error message at a search engine, it should have given you a few hints already.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question both here and on Slack. It will be the same people that answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using "\" in my path, I used "/" instead and it worked fine.

Comment: Backslashes are the correct path separator in MS Windows, which makes your problem even more unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the script executions are platform-dependent because of the path slash characters. Kindly install WSL and execute the above operations.